# Call a function only for homepage, then stop it for any other page, then call it for homepage again

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a website with a bit of AJAX functionality and some animated effects.

When a user arrives to the homepage of the website, a function is called that turns on a simple image rotator. That banner rotator is located only on homepage, so it would make no sense to call the function is a user begins browsing the website from any other page:

```
if (location.pathname.length <= 1) {
animate_hero_images();
}
```

After the very fist page has loaded, and a user starts navigation around the site by clicking on links, AJAX kicks in, and all the other pages load into whichever page has been the first the user arrived to.

**Problem # 1:** if a user first arrives to a page that is NOT the homepage, and only later loads the homepage via AJAX, `animate_hero_images` function doesn't get called (the banner rotator is disabled).

**Problem # 2:** if a user first arrives to a homepage, then navigates to some other pages, and then comes back to the homepage again, doe to a number of specific issues with that particular site that I unfortunately have no control over, `animate_hero_images` function loads with a noticeable delay, and doesn't work properly.

I tried to solve both problem by calling `animate_hero_images` function again on `click` event. But it solves the problem only partially: if the user starts from a NON-homepage and then loads the homepage, the function gets called, and the image rotator works just fine. But if the user starts at the homepage, goes somewhere else, and comes back to the homepage, the function gets called ok, and then a few moments later the same function kicks in from the previous call, and the images begin to rotate a lot faster, and with weird irregular rhythm.

My solution is to call the function for the homepage, then on click stop the function, then once the new page is loaded, if it's homepage, call the function again.

I use this snippet to disable the function:

```
$("body").on('click', '.ajax-link a', function(event) { 
animate_hero_images = function() {};
// do all sorts of other stuff
}
```

Somehow, this doesn't work: when I arrive back to homepage via AJAX, the wayward function switches on.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check time intervals of functions, this might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd check against the existence of the hero image container rather than the `location.pathname`:

```
function animate_homepage() {
    if($('#hero-container-id-here').length > 0)
    {
        // call animation function here
    }
});
```

...and then call that whenever new content is loaded via the AJAX success() method (if that's what you're using). The animation function should only then fire when your hero images actually exist on the page.

You may need to put this is a timeout if your content fades in; one reason why your current solution may not be working is that you're calling the function on a click event, which is firing before the homepage content is loaded onto the page.